# Simplifying a fraction with a binomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to simplify this fraction:

$$\frac{a^{-3}+b^{-3}}{a^{-2}-b^{-2}}$$

So I am not sure if I am allowed to do that, but since the exponents were negative, I decided to invert the equation to get positive exponents and then work my way through simplification:

$$\frac{a^{2}-b^{2}}{a^{3}+b^{3}}$$

Then I used difference of squares:

$$\frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{a^{3}+b^{3}}$$

However, I got stuck on this part because I don't know how to simplify
$$a^3 + b^3$$

I could simplify it like this:

$$\frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{(a+b)(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})}$$
then cancel out:

$$\frac{(a-b)}{(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})}$$

But wouldn't that still need more simplification?

I am not sure if it can be simplified more or if my inverting of the numerator and denominator are allowed, is it allowed to invert the equation like I did?

Comment: Your simplification is invalid, you have to multiply by $a^{-2} + b^{-2}$, the conjugate of  $a^{-2} + b^{-2}$ on the top and bottom. This method is similar to the method used to evaluate complex numbered fractions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all $$\frac{a^{-3}+b^{-3}}{a^{-2}-b^{-2}} \color{red} \neq \frac{a^{2}-b^{2}}{a^{3}+b^{3}}$$

The correct simplification is :$$\frac{a^{-3}+b^{-3}}{a^{-2}-b^{-2}}=\frac{a^{3}+b^{3}}{ab(b^{2}-a^{2})}$$

Now, $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$

Therefore :

$$\frac{a^{3}+b^{3}}{ab(b^{2}-a^{2})}=\frac{(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)}{ab(b-a)(b+a)}=\color{blue}{\frac{(a^2-ab+b^2)}{ab(b-a)}}$$

That's probably most simplified version of your given expression.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "simple" reduction of your fraction. Have a look at [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cleft(a%5E%7B-3%7D%2Bb%5E%7B-3%7D%5Cright)%2F%5Cleft(a%5E%7B-2%7D-b%5E%7B-2%7D%5Cright)).

Comment: There is a minus sign in the denominator.

Comment: Astute observation

Comment: Go on Allan ... edit you're answer ... so I can give you +1 too.

Comment: Everything in my answer is correct, thanks

Comment: The link is correct ... so ... there is a reduction...

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\frac{1}{a^3}+\frac{1}{b^3}}{\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}}$$
$$\frac{a^3+b^3}{(b^2-a^2)(ab)}$$
$$\frac{a^2+b^2-ab}{(b-a)(ab)}$$

Comment: Bracket needed in the denominator of the second line.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Comment acknowledged

Answer (score 0):

Your first inversion is incorrect.  It is not the case the $a^2-b^2=\frac 1{a^{-2}-b^{-2}}$  The right blows up when $a=b$ while the left is zero, for example.  You could do $frac 1{a^{-2}-b^{-2}}=\frac {a^2b^2}{b^2-a^2}$ by multiplying through by $a^2b^2$, but that may not be the most useful thing here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invert the equation because inversion works by multiplying the top and bottom by the variable to a positive exponent. 
For example:
$\frac{3}{x^-3} = \frac{3}{\frac{1}{x^3}} * \frac{x^3}{x^3} = \frac{3x^3}{1}$.
You should instead write the expression as nested fractions and follow the rest of the steps like in TheDeadLegend's answer.